# Some css is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I am working on the application. Some of the css are not working in IE, whereas working in Firefox, such as Scrollbar,  `input` types, `placeholder`, `required` etc. All of the things are working fine in Firefox as well as Chrome, but not in IE. My IE version is 9.
My Firefox view is

[image]

whereas my IE view is -

[image]

My css code is -

```
        input[type="submit"]{

          background:#3399cc;
          width:100%;
          border:0;
          padding:4%;
          font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
          font-size:100%;
          color:#fff;
          cursor:pointer;
          transition:background .3s;
          -webkit-transition:background .3s;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover{
          background:#EE2C2C;
        }


input[type="text"]{
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  margin-bottom:2%;
  margin-top:2%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:4%;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size:95%;
  color:black;
}


input[type="password"]{
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  margin-bottom:2%;
  margin-top:2%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:4%;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size:95%;
  color:black;
}
```

I tried to figure out the issue by so many ways such as change Compatibility View, try but unsucceed.

My html file is -

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

    <html>
<head>



<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/imageIcon.png" />
<title> IETM Solutions </title>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ietmLogin.css" type="text/css"></link>
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");

System.out.println("session -- A1 - " + session);

 if(session != null)
{
    session.invalidate();
    session = null;
} 
System.out.println("session -- A2 - " + session);
%>
</head>
<body>
<div id="LoginImage">
<div id="login">
<h1>IETM Document Management System</h1>

   <form action="Login" method="post">  

        <table>
     <tr>   
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="UserName" required = "true"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required = "true"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>  
            </tr>

            </table>
   </form>
</div>

<%

String error = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
//System.out.println("error : "+ error);
if(error != null)
{
    %>
<h4 align="center" style="color: red">Invalid User Name/Password</h4>
<% }

%>


 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion/solution will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in IE so something else is causing it to fail

Comment: This should work. What is your doctype? Please add your html (header)

Comment: can you post your html too?

Comment: I change the Compatibility View to IE8. Even not working in 8 also.

Comment: @atmd The hell it isn't. How on earth could you possibly think that, considering password fields have been around since the dawn of time?

Comment: I. . . Don't know. I swear canIuse said it wasn't supported below 10. Need to stop drinking in the afternoon. Or start.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=input, http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

IE is rendering in Quirks Mode, which doesn't support most styles on `<input>` elements.

Comment: would using HTML5 shiv help as well?

Comment: @MrPickles Possibly, but it shouldn't make any difference for this chunk of HTML/CSS. One thing that may help is adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to force IE into its most standards-compliant mode.

Comment: '@Niet the Dark Absol' ok, Thought I was ask as I was just about to post with the suggestion when your post went up

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your HTML one question knocking me repeatedly. You drew a table only with `<table> and <tr>` tags but where is `<td>` tag which is equally required for drawing table as well? I just simply rewrote your html and it worked fine for me:

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="UserName" required="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

IE9 is not smart enough to understand markup error. If this works fine in your case please don't forget to widen or style  and  for more room.

Comment: And also I will request you to add HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` at first line of your document and `html5shiv.js` so that IE can receive HTML5 new semantic tags.